Etymologie de "bavure policière"
Même si certains dictionnaires (comme le cnrtl) ne l'attestent pas, l'expression "bavure policière" est présentement largement répandue dans les médias pour qualifier des abus de pouvoir violents de la part des forces de l'ordre.
Je ne parviens pas à trouver l'origine de cet usage (mis à part le fait qu'il aurait été argotique). Une hypothèse qui me vient mais ne se repose pas sur grand-chose serait la BAV, une brigade aux méthodes particulièrement violentes.
Cette hypothèse tient-elle la route?

Ben juste que "baver" c'est pas beau, et c'est une "erreur" quand on mange. Ou bien "baver" quand le stylo fuit, ce qui n'est pas beau non plus. Au lieu d'écrire une belle page d'ordre et de paix civile harmonieuse, y'a une bavure au milieu de la page, et c'est pas beau.

Bavure policière suggère qu'il y a eu violences ayant entraîné la mort. pas nécessairement bavure professionnelle.

@FrançoisJurain Les bavures policières n'entraînent pas nécessairement la mort.

@FrançoisJurain Je suis d'accord avec  jlliagre. Je ne suis pas juriste mais je dirais qu'il y a bavure policière dès lors que le représentant des forces de l'ordre commet un acte  qui est en dehors du cadre de ses attributions, c'est bien en deça de l'acte de donner la mort. Je ne sais pas s'il y a une définition juridique de la bavure policière (et j'en serais étonné) mais on peut voir ce qu'en dit  Dominique Tricaud dans l'interview qu'il a donné à la revue Hommes&Migrations

Non bavure policière n'est pas un terme juridique. Bavure tout court non plus; je ne prétends pas que les bavures policières entraînent nécessairement la mort. Par contre le choix du terme par le locuteur (qui, par implication, n'est ni policier ni juriste ni magistrat ou s'il l'est, ne s'exprime pas à titre professionnel) suggère, comme je l'ai écrit, qu'il y a eu mort d'homme.

@FrançoisJurain Où vois-tu une suggestion de "mort"? "Des abus de pouvoir violents" ne suggèrent pas la mort de quiconque.

En effet, les "abus de pouvoir violents" d'une définition de dictionnaire ne suggèrent rien du tout. Ce qui suggère, c'est le fait que le locuteur choisit cette expression à la place de "violence abusive", "arrestation musclée", "brutalité injustifiée" ou toute autre expression non juridique.

Par exemple, on trouve dans fr.WP, dans l'intro à l'entrée "violence policière": On parle de bavures policières dans les cas les plus graves, en particulier dans les cas conduisant à la mort de la personne attaquée. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violence_polici%C3%A8re. Manifestement, l'expression suggère à l'auteur de cette entrée la même chose qu'à moi. On parle: ce n'est pas le lexicographe réserve le terme.

Tu vas trop loin dans ton interprétation personnelle.

@Frank ce n'est pas moi personnellement qui ai écrit cette entrée de WP. Ce n'est pas moi qui écris les titres d'articles de journaux qui contiennent cette expression. Mon interprétation est au vu de l'une et des autres.

Bof. Wikipedia n'est pas toujours une référence.

@AnneAunyme Comme tu dis, le TLF n'atteste pas cette étymologie donc il y a très peu de chances, surtout que le sens figuré est quand même une explication assez évidente.

@guillaume31 le TLF n'atteste pas du tout de cette expression, ce qui en dit plus long sur son incomplétude que sur l'étymologie de l'expression. Il me parait assez improbable qu'il y ait un saut de "imperfection" à "crime voire meurtre" sans étape intermédiaire.

@AnneAunyme mais l'explication que tu proposes toi n'est même pas une étape intermédiaire, c'est carrément une réinterprétation... "Bavure" = "coulure", synonyme de travail mal fait. C'est ce qui est expliqué ici par les correcteurs du Monde par exemple. Je ne sais pas s'il y a eu des évolutions dans l'expression, je dis juste que le sens figuré, imagé est le plus plausible.

La bavure n'est pas uniquement policière, la bavure peut-être commise dans de nombreux contextes autres que policier ou militaire. Et l'expression bavure policière est peut-être familière mais pas argotique. Le TLF, même s'il n'est pas explicite en ne faisant pas figurer textuellement bavure policière (ou bavure militaire),  permet de retracer l'évolution du sens du mot bavure au sens figuré.
La bavure c'est quelque chose qui fait saillie, qui ressort et qui ne devrait pas être là. Du sens propre (A dans le TLF) on est passé au sens figuré (B dans le TLF).
Le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française fait remonter le premier emploi au sens propre au XVIIIe siècle.

Trace, saillie, que les joints d'un moule laissent sur l'objet moulé (Saillie, trace de métal, de plâtre, de ciment,...)

Le TLF donne ce sens en A-3..
Ensuite on trouve au XIXe siècle :

Tache produite par l'excès d'un produit liquide qui coule. Bavure d'encre dans un dessin, une épreuve en imprimerie. Bavures dans un maquillage.

Le TLF donne ce sens en A-1.
Là où peut-être le TLF ne s'étend pas assez, c'est sur le sens figuré,  mais Le Robert est très clair :

Erreur, abus aux conséquences fâcheuses.

La locution sans bavure, (signalée comme familière dans le DCLF) date, elle, du  XIXe siècle. Et le TLF en donne un exemple de 1945 où bavure est bien employé au sens figuré :

le Général de Gaulle, sans fausse poésie, sans la moindre sensiblerie, en phrases nettes et sans bavures, a rappelé la vérité française éternelle (F. Mauriac, 1945)

Si c'est « sans bavures » au sens figuré, c'est qu'il n'y a rien qui fait tache, rien qui dépasse, rien qui choque les sens.
Le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française signale l'apparition de l'emploi militaire « figuré et courant1 »  du mot bavure  au XXe siècle pour parler d'« erreur pratique, abus ayant des conséquences fâcheuses, parfois dramatiques. Des bavures policières ».
Un ngram permet de voir que l'expression bavure policière s'est répandue dans la deuxième moitié du XXe siècle. Elle est devenue courante au milieu des années 1970 et il est fort possible que ce soit la chanson de Coluche Le flic (sortie en 1975) qui l'ait popularisée :

... Eh, une fois c'est arrivé ! On a tapé sur un flic ! Ah, la crise eh !
Ils ont dit que c'était une bavure !
T'aurais vu la gueule de la bavure !
Moi, ça m'a fait passer l'envie de baver !

L'expression est assez répandue en 1979 pour qu'elle apparaisse lors du débat parlementaire du 13 novembre examinant des crédits du ministère de l'intérieur2.
La neuvième édition du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française, commencée en 1986, donne :

Fig. et fam. Défaut, imperfection qu’il eût été facile d’éviter. Dans ce chapitre, j’ai relevé quelques bavures. Un ouvrage sans la moindre bavure. Un travail net et sans bavures. Spécialement. Fam. Incident inattendu et malencontreux, erreur ou faute dans le déroulement d’une opération, d’un plan d’action. Une opération menée sans bavure. Une bavure policière.

Bref, non, l'hypothèse d'une BAV (Brigade des agressions et violences, ancêtre des BAC) qui aurait donné son nom aux bavures policières ne tient pas la route, si ce n'est à des fins humoristiques. Le mot bavure s'employait déjà au sens figuré avant la création des BAV (1953).
On parle de bavure policière, comme on parle de bavure médicale :

Bavure médicale : l'enfant reçoit 20 fois la dose prescrite (La Provence, 07/12/2019)

de bavure sociale :

le premier flic de France aurait-il commis une bavure sociale (Libération 20/02/2013)

de bavure professionnelle (qui peut-être policière, mais pas que):

Le père a versé dans l’alcool, consommation discrète et mesurée, mais incessante, qui ne peut que mener un jour à la bavure professionnelle. (L'humanité du 26/02/92)


1 Ce qui ne veut pas dire argotique.
2 Compte rendu de la séance parue au Journal Officiel du 14 novembre 1979.

Attention, les premières apparitions de bavure policière rapportées par Google Ngrams sont de faux positifs. Celui de 1939 a en fait été publié en 1996. L'auteure d'un ouvrage prétendument daté de 1966 n'avait que trois ans à cette date...

@jlliagre Tout à fait possible, en effet, je n'ai pas trouvé l'article lui-même et la date est probablement celle de la publication du premier numéro de la revue. Merci.

La BAV à laquelle je fais référence a précisément sévie à partir des années 1970 donc justement les informations temporelles que vous apportez corroborent cette hypothèse.

Une "bavure policière" n'est pas synonyme de "agressions et violences". C'est une agression/violence commise par la police et la BAV était plutôt réputée en commettre. Par contre il semble bien que j'ai fait erreur au niveau des dates mais ça n'invalide pas l'hypothèse (l'expression aurait pu prendre 10 ans à se populariser)

Honnêtement, l'explication la plus simple est l'analogie avec la bavure du stylo à encre qui fait tâche sur la page... ou la trace/saillie de None. Ceci dit, "la BAV? que des bavures!" serait un jeu de mot assez évident. Ca rime tout seul. Je serais un opposant, je dirais: "les baveux de la BAV? Experts en bavures!"

@Frank Excellent jeu de mots!

@None Tu parles! C'est pas charitable d'ironiser comme ça haha :-)
